# как сделать выпадающее меню чтобы открывалось на всю ширину контейнера? Спасибо!

Tags: css

Есть меню

```
ЛОГО      home, about, blog, service, contact = ширина этого контейнера 977 px;
```

как сделать чтобы подменю  раскрывалось от начала контейнера т.е от лого, то конца т.е contact ? когда наводим на Service

```html
<li class="down_menu"><a href="">Service</a>
  <ul class="service">
    <li ><a href="">Shared Office Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Shared Office Space</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Shared Office Space</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Просто написать ширину хардом вам не подходит?

Comment: если задать ширину выпадающего меню, то выравнивать его потом как?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего подойдет решение с комбинацией `position absolute/relative`. Вот пример( если я правильно понял вопрос)

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
}

.service {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.down_menu:hover .service {
  display: block;
}

.parent>li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="parent">
    <li><a href="">First level</a></li>
    <li><a href="">First level</a></li>
    <li><a href="">First level</a></li>
    <li class="down_menu">
    <a href="">Service</a>
      <ul class="service">
        <li><a href="">Shared Office Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Shared Office Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Shared Office Space</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```